# How to make simple sliding down divs with jquery

Tags: jquery, html

Ok, 
I'm new to jquery and just learning.
I have a bunch of div's that I'd like to have sliding down every 2 seconds or so in one box.
So for example, maybe a picture of an apple, then replaced with an orange, and so on....
Is there a simple way to do this with jquery?
(I don't care about whether the visitors hovers his mouse over the div, or anything like that).

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean the turndown effect here: http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle/? (or even the [scrollDown effect on their beginner demos page](http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle/begin.html)?)

Answer (score 1):

jQuery has slideDown and SlideUp methods that you could use. For example you could have two or more divs on top of each other (using the appropriate z-index) and then use the above methods to show the appropriate one.